# How to make Laravel charts using ajax and morris.js?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, morris.js

i want to make graphs in laravel andi have done somethings in it.

I followed a tutorial from 
[maxoffsky.com](http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/creating-bar-graphs-with-ajax-and-morris-laravel/)

Now i had followed this tutorial but , this done over here: 
Like converting the eloquent query to JOSN. I didnt understood how to do this with my query,

```
$range = CarbonCarbon::now()->subDays(30);
$stats = DB::table('sales_flat_order_items as w')
                ->leftJoin('sales_flat_orders as s', 's.entity_id','=','w.order_id')=
                ->where('qty_canceled','=','0')
                ->where('s.created_at','>=',$range)
                ->groupBy('s.created_at')
                ->orderBy('s.created_at')
                ->get([DB::Raw('DATE(s.created_at) days'),DB::Raw('sum(w.qty_ordered) as qty_ordered']);


        return View::make('sales_flat_orders.orderbydate', compact('stats'));
```

i would like to know to to convert $stats to json and to display the list of only qty_ordered and date in View.

I also have a view named orderbydate, where i m displaying some tables and some js which show the bar chart.

I am not able to understand the exact flow to make a dynamic graph. ie. values taken from the database

I think first we need to convert the eloquent query to Array or JSON, I understood that if I was using only a single model, then the

> magic method _toString()

would have converted this query into JSON and then to popluate the data on the bar chart or a pie chart or any other.

Comment: give a clear question. what exactly do you want?

Comment: I want to populate value on my bar chart from database itself using json ,

Comment: put an example of the format of json.

Comment: [{"amount_refunded":"93603.0000","row_total":"2866074.4500","discount_amount":"60425.8000","tax_amount":"0.0000","qty_ordered":"1609.0000","subtotal":"5482387.3400","total_invoiced":"5170433.2400","shipping_amount":"13347.7000"}]